# How to get figure for web traffic + how to append column to numpy array?

Tags: python, html, url, web, numpy

I'd like to know how to append a column to a numpy array? Assuming I read in a .tsv as follows :

```
  from sklearn import metrics,preprocessing,cross_validation
  from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
  import sklearn.linear_model as lm
  import pandas as p    
  print "loading data.."
  traindata = np.array(p.read_table('train.tsv')) #here is where I am unsure what to do
```

The first column of traindata holds the URL of each webpage.

The logic I would like after this is :

```
for each row in traindata
          #run function to look up traffic webpage is getting, store this in a numpy array
Add a new column to traindata numpy array, append on the data in the array created into our "for each"
```

How can this be accomplished generally, even if you just use a "filler" method for retrieving web traffic? :)

Thanks!

```
Inputs and outputs : 
    Input : Numpy array of 26 columns.
    We call a function on the value in the first column of each row, this function will return a number.
    We append all these numbers into a numpy array with one column.
    We append the Numpy array with 26 cols to the one made above to end up with a numpy array with 27 columns.
Output : Numpy array of 26 columns.
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: You have two very different questions here. One question at a time please.

Comment: @JanDvorak Thanks for the info! I have fixed the question now - the tool was the unimportant part, I just need a way to get the figures :)

Comment: @msvalkon You're right, I will adjust this into two questions now. Please give me a moment. Apologies.

Comment: For your first part - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041371/alexa-api

Comment: @msvalkon Thanks for the suggestion - this question is now for the Python/numpy appending, I have asked the other question here (keeping in mind the suggestion of @JanDvorak) here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961319/how-to-get-figure-for-web-traffic . Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I assume you meant "Output : Numpy array of 27 columns." instead of 26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [numpy.hstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) to append columns, like this:

```
import numpy as np

def some_function(x):
    return 3*x

input = np.ones([10,26])
input = np.hstack([input,np.empty([input.shape[0],1])])
for row in input:
    row[-1] = some_function(row[0])

output = input
```

Comment: Thank you for this. What can I run in my for each to append a value to the column of the numpy array I am making here? Thanks :)

Comment: Can you please give some examples of what would be your input and output? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I don't like about numpy.hstack or numpy.c_ is that they aren't flexible enough to work on a 2-dimensional or 1-dimensional array.

For example, if I'm trying to calculate a value based on, say, the magnitude of a vector, and append it to that vector (like lifting a point to the paraboloid in a Delaunay triangulation problem), I'd like that function to work for a single 1D array or an array of 1D arrays. The function that I ended up with is:

```py
def append_last_dim(array_in, array_augment):
    newshape = list(array_in.T.shape)
    newshape[0] += 1
    ret_array = np.empty(newshape)
    ret_array[:-1] = array_in.T
    ret_array[-1] = array_augment
    return ret_array.T
```

Example:

```py
point_list = np.random.rand(5,4)
list_augment = point_list**2.sum(axis=-1) # shape (5,)

%timeit aug_array = append_last_dim(point_list,array_augment)
# 1.68 µs ± 19.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

point = point_list[0] # shape (4,)
augment = list_augment[0] # shape ()

%timeit append_last_dim(point, augment)
# 1.24 µs ± 9.78 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

def lift_point(point):  # this works for 1 point or array of points
  return append_last_dim(point,(point**2).sum(axis-1))

lift_point(point_list).shape  # (5,5)
lift_point(point).shape  # (5,)
```

numpy.c_ works with the array of points as-is, but is 10x slower and doesn't work for a single input array:

```
%timeit retval = np.c_[point_list,array_augment]
# 13.8 µs ± 47.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

np.c_[point,augment]
# ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, 
# but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 4 and the array at 
# index 1 has size 1
```

np.hstack and np.append don't work on the arguments as-is, as `point_list` and `point_augment` are of different dimensions, but if you reshape `point_augment`, then it the result is still ~2x slower and can't handle a single input or array of inputs with a unified call:

```py
%timeit np.hstack((point_list,point_augment.reshape(5,1)))
# 3.49 µs ± 21.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.append(point_list,point_augment.reshape((5,1)),axis=1)
# 2.45 µs ± 7.91 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Here are times for a list of 1000 points:

```
point_1k_list = np.random.rand(5,4)
point_augment = (point_1k_list**2).sum(axis=-1)

%timeit append_last_dim(point_1k_list,point_augment)
# 3.91 µs ± 35 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.append(point_1k_list,point_augment.reshape((1000,1)),axis=1)
# 6.5 µs ± 140 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.hstack((point_1k_list,point_augment.reshape((1000,1))))
# 7.82 µs ± 31.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.c_[point_1k_list,point_augment]
# 19.3 µs ± 234 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

I'm not sure why I can't find better built-in support in numpy for handling single-point or vectorized data, like the 'lift_point' function above.